# Convert UITextView text into [String], separating paragraphs into the Strings

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview

I have an `iOS` project using `Xcode 7` and `Swift3`.  I have a `UITextView` that enables the user to save that text via `NSUserDefaults` into a `String` variable.  However, if the user has a lot of text that includes paragraphs, when they save the text, it compiles it together to be one big long string of text, not recognizing the original paragraphs.

How do I have the string of text in essence recognize there are paragraphs and then make them into separate strings that are part of a `[String]`?  Is this possible?

Example of text:

```
This is a complex task for me.

I don't know how to do this.
```

After the user names this text, which is two separate small paragraphs, it would save to `NSUserDefaults` as:

```
This is a complex task for me.  I don't know how to do this.
```

I know rather than save a `String` to `NSUserDefaults` I need to instead use a `[String]`, but I still can't figure out how to take a `UITextView` and convert it's text into the string array, separating each paragraph into a separate `String`.

Comment: there is a new line character between those two lines.

Comment: So if I convert the `UITextView` text into an `NSString` can I then use textView.components(separatedBy: \n) and it would separate them based on detecting a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the reference in Apple's documents concerning paragraphs.  I then took the advice and did the following:

```
// Assign the text to an NSString Variable
var newTextNS = instructions.text! as NSString

// Separate the text paragraphs into String Variables
var newArray = newTextNS.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

I then had an array with all the different paragraphs as separate String variables.

Worked just as I needed it too.

Comment: There is no need to use `NSString`. `String` has the `components(separatedBy:)` method.

Answer (score -2):

Please check Apple's reference [Words, Paragraphs, and Line Breaks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html)

```
NSArray *arr = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

or

```
NSString *string = /* assume this exists */;

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);

[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:range

                           options:NSStringEnumerationByParagraphs

                        usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable paragraph, NSRange paragraphRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {             // ... }];
```

Hope it helps.